# daily average after applying diff

Tags: r

I have a datasets with 3-hourly values and I want to compute daily averages, but I have to do it over the difference between 2 consecutive timesteps. This is a sample of my data:

```
      prec=
      c(5068.51904296875, 5068.53076171875, 5068.5654296875, 5068.5927734375, 
      5068.60107421875, 5068.60107421875, 5068.60107421875, 5068.60205078125, 
      5068.6123046875, 5068.6171875, 5068.6171875, 5068.6171875, 5068.6171875, 
      5068.6171875, 5068.6171875, 5068.6171875, 5068.61865234375, 5068.646484375, 
      5068.662109375, 5068.6669921875, 5068.67138671875, 5068.6728515625, 
      5068.7138671875, 5068.74169921875)

      days=
      structure(c(7670, 7670, 7670, 7670, 7670, 7670, 7670, 7670, 7671, 
      7671, 7671, 7671, 7671, 7671, 7671, 7671, 7672, 7672, 7672, 7672, 
      7672, 7672, 7672, 7672), class = "Date")
```

So, I would have to do:

```
    dfprec <- diff(prec,lag=1)
```

My question is, how could I get now daily means?? I could use `aggregate` or `tapply`..but now `dfprec` has one "time" less in days ...
Any suggestion?

Comment: You have to add one NA: `c(NA, dfprec)` or `c(dfprec, NA)` to get the same length as the original vector.

Comment: can you specify what behaviour at the limit of each day? Do you want each difference to be attributed to the previous or the next timestep? or maybe not take into account the first or last difference of each day?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to keep the size of the vector?

This seems to work fine:

```
res <- tapply(prec, days, function(p) {mean(diff(p))})
res
#   1991-01-01   1991-01-02   1991-01-03 
# 0.0118582589 0.0006975446 0.0175781250
```

Comment: I don't think it should be necessary to throw out the first measurement on each day. I'd probably do `tapply(c(NA, diff(prec)), days, FUN = mean, na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: does it change the result?

Comment: Yes, it does, since it uses observations that are thrown out here (difference between the first obs on one day and the last obs on the prior day).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for; That way seems to work for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use the shift function from library data.table:

```
DT1 = data.table(prec,days)

DT1[,dprec := prec - shift(prec,1), by=days][,mean(dprec,na.rm = TRUE),by=days]
```